# Change the text in revisions page when bounty ends with no winning answer

Tags: feature-request, bounties, wording, expired-bounty

When a bounty is over with no winning answer ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/58842/revisions)) the text is:

> Bounty Ended with no winning answer by [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)♦

While as a programmer I can see the reason behind this, removing my programmer hat I really believe it better be only:

> Bounty Ended with no winning answer

Comment: Well, the event itself is really "Bounty Ended by Community" with the side-note that there was no winning answer. I think the message makes perfect sense, I see no need to change it. This is how all messages are formed in the revision history... If you *really* want to nitpick, just add the word "chosen" after "no winning answer" so it matches the other Bounty Ended events.

Comment: @animuson you mean the Community user has ended the bounty? The Community user wrote the no winning answer? Sorry, can't find the sense.

Comment: What doesn't make sense about the Community user ending the bounty and not choosing any winning answer? Community is acting on behalf of the system. The system looked over the question, determined that no answers were eligible to receive the bounty automatically, and **chose no one**. That action is attributed to Community. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: @animuson each and his own. I still find "Bounty Ended with no winning answer" as more fitting. Bounty had winning answer? Good, let's see who  chose that answer in addition to linking the answer itself. No winning answer? No need for any further details or links.

Comment: Looks like this very question is going to be new example, lol!

Comment: I think it would be better as "Bounty ended with no winning answer" :-) ( lower-case **e** )

Comment: @ben not sure about that. "Bounty Ended" is the event name, same like "Post Closed" and all other events/messages.

Answer (score 3):

This should be easily fixable. The fact that the message says "no winning answer" and  indicates that this case is already detected in the code that creates the message. Comparing with other bounty messages:

[image: chosen by Rachel]

For more examples, see [the numerous bounties on this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/125740/revisions)

In this case, "by Community♦" adds no useful information, so it should simply be removed. In contrast, in messages where an answer was automatically picked:

[image: autobounty msg]

saying that Community chose the answer *is* informative, and should be kept (or changed to "chosen automatically" or similar).

Comment: Yup, agreed. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still very against removing the user from the event. *Someone* ended the bounty. Any time you have an event that can be completed by a user, a user should always be present with the event. Otherwise you wind up with inconsistency and confusion. How about just rearranging the text to emphasize that Community *ended the bounty* (and not necessarily chose anyone), like so:

> **Bounty Ended** by [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) ♦ with no winning answer

and similarly for a winning answer:

> **Bounty Ended** by [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) ♦ with [**not Community's answer**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) chosen

I don't know how feasible it is to re-order the words in an event, but completely removing the user from the event sounds even more infeasible.

Comment: Still disagree but good point about consistency with other system messages.